# Android Wear DotsPageIndicator only fades when first created

Tags: android, wear-os

I have added a `DotsPageIndicator` to my GridPager which works fine.

The only problem i am facing is the fade of the dots. When first displaying my ui the dots are visible for a brief moment and than fade away. When i swipe to a different page the dots reappear and from thereon out they don't disappear anymore.

I have not touched the [setDotFadeWhenIdle(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/DotsPageIndicator.html#setDotFadeWhenIdle(boolean)) property. Is there anything else i have to consider?

Comment: See me answer. [Stackoverflow link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097736/android-wear-dotspageindicator-fades-first-time-instead-of-always-visible/30269245#30269245)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Works as advertised. Hope to see a proper fix soon.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it extending WearableActivity and enabling Ambient mode. See doc https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/always-on.html#EnableAmbient

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! It would be nice if you could include some of the relevant information from the link you posted in your answer, as links may become invalid in the future. Please also read [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) for more information. =)