# Android Wear DotsPageIndicator fades first time instead of always visible

Tags: android, android-viewpager, wear-os

DotsPageIndicator always fades out the first time it is shown. I tried `setDotFadeWhenIdle(false);` but then it fades out and never comes back. I just want it to be shown all the time and never fade out.

I saw this question: [Android Wear DotsPageIndicator only fades when first created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28141808/android-wear-dotspageindicator-only-fades-when-first-created)
but this never got answered.

I hope somebody can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spent days on trying to figure out what's wrong with many different combinations.  I think it's a bug.

My solution until they fix it.

```
 app:dotFadeOutDelay="100000"
```

Comment: I think you're right! I'm just leaving it as it is.